# How to change guest user icon

Tags: 12.04, unity, customization, users

How the "Guest User" picture in Ubuntu 12.04 can be changed?

The user picture appear, for example, in the [user menu](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/usuariosf.png/).

This image is seen in every user's menu, so I guess it's just a matter of finding where the silhouetted bust image is, and being able to change it or creating a soft link with its name to the desired substitute picture.

EDIT:
Since the Guest User would never see the picture, I figure that there is nothing I would put in `/etc/guest-session/skel/` (as per [How do I change the guest session defaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9515/how-do-i-change-the-guest-session-defaults)) or in `/etc/skel/` (a folder mentioned in [how to change default launcher icons in unity for a new user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38331/how-to-change-default-launcher-icons-in-unity-for-a-new-user))?

Comment: A screenshot of what you want to change would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the user icon that appears in the user switching menu, I don't think it is possible.

You should be able to simply put the user icon in a file called `.face` in `/etc/guest-session/skel/`.

However, I just tried doing this, and it doesn't seem to work at all, for although the `.face` file shows up when logged into the guest account, it does not show in the fast user switching menu. When logged into the guest account, "Guest Session" doesn't even show up in the menu, so I don't know if it would show then.

Comment: Indeed, the icon would show in any account's User menu, except for the Guest user account itself.